# Data attribute for ChoiceField option

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a form with next field:

```
phone_code = forms.ChoiceField(
        label=_('Phone code'),
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'short'})
)
```

I need to add data-attribute to `<option>` to store country code for each phone code. I'm trying to do it in the next way: in template I render this field the next way:

```
                        <select name="{{ phone_code_field.name }}">
                            {% for choice in phone_code_field.field.extra_data %}
                                <option data-choice-code="{{ choice.0.0 }}" value="{{ choice.0.1 }}">{{ choice.1 }}</option>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </select>
```

extra_data is a data-structure where
 I store phone code and country code for each choice.

**Question:** But after error validation the chosen value of phone-code is the first choice in the selector, not the last selected choice. If field is rendered automatically by django forms(`{{ form.phone_code }}`), it works correct, but in this case I have to override Select widget. How can I implement this in the way I do?

Or how can I define in template which attribute should be selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on rendering the field manually, then you also have to determine manually which item is selected, and output the `selected` attribute on the relevant one.

```
{% for choice in phone_code_field.field.extra_data %}
    <option {% if phone_code_field.field.value == choice.0.1 %}selected="selected"{% endif %} data-choice-code="{{ choice.0.0 }}" value="{{ choice.0.1 }}">{{ choice.1 }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you. I also had a thought about this but implemented it in a different way: `{% if choice.0.1 == contacts_form.cleaned_data.phone_code %}selected="selected"{% endif %}`